# jQuery: submit dropdown selection, return success message

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, submit

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
    var fname = $('#fname').attr('value');
    var lname = $('#lname').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "fname="+ fname +"&amp; lname="+ lname,
            success: function(){
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can I alter it so that it takes the value of a dropdown box only?

Comment: Umm for one thing: we have **no idea** what your html looks like... so we have **no idea** what the dropdown is....

Comment: Variables are cheap. I would just `.serialize()` the whole form as the data (vs. the 'manual' method you're using), and let the back end pick and choose which parts are important. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Like this, but I suggest you when creating data parameter for jQuery ajax methods pass it as object, then jQuery will encode all string and you will have correct url, and correct data will be passed to your script.
e.g.

```
data : {fname = fname, lname = lname }
```

in order to pass only value from your dropdown box do it this way

```
data: { your_variable : $('#id_of_drop_down_box').val() }
```

so your method will look like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#submit").submit(function() {
// we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
var fname     = $('#fname').attr('value');
var lname     = $('#lname').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: { your_variable : $('#id_of_drop_down_box').val() },
        success: function(){
            $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
return false;
});
});
```

and remember "your_variable" is name that you will collect from $_POST global variable in php. So if you name it "MyDropDownBox" then in php you will access it

```
$var = $_POST["MyDropDownBox"]
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper jQuery methods. Use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`. That goes for every form element (input, textarea, select). Other suggestions could be to use the short method for POST - `$.post()`, pass your data as `object` - `data: { fname: fname, lname: lname }`

Answer (score 0):

Use [.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for getting your dropdown selected value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#submit").submit(function() {
    /* Get the dropdown selected value using .val() */
    var value = $("#dropdown").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php",
      /* Send dropdown selected value as a parameter */
      data: { dropdown: value },
      success: function(){
        $('form#submit').hide(function(){
          $('div.success').fadeIn();
        });
      }
    });
  return false;
  });
});
```

Merely modify `#dropdown` with your dropdown's `id`.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I click submit something appears to happens, but the success/fail message never shows.

Comment: @BrianByrne, You need to modify the dropdown's id and data parameter accordingly. Did you do it?